# Problems with moving a div by cursor if I move it too fast

Tags: javascript, html

to specify my question I wrote an standalone example of my problem. I want to precisely move a div inside a wrapping container (only in x-direction), like a trackbar. The wrapping div should specify the space for the slider.

My script works, if I slowly move the cursor. But if I move the cursor too fast I kind of loose the slider div somewhere inside the container. Especially in the right and left corner.

How can I improve the code to have a stable solution, without the need of librarys? I know that there is a kind of simple solution with jQuery, but I would be very happy if we could find a way in plain javascript.

```js
var x_mouse_position;
var x_offset;
var isDown = false;
var new_slider_left_position;

var container = document.getElementById("container");
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    isDown = true;
    x_offset = slider.offsetLeft - e.clientX;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    isDown = false;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {

    if (isDown) {
        x_mouse_position = event.clientX;

        new_slider_left_position = x_mouse_position + x_offset;

        if (new_slider_left_position >= 0 && new_slider_left_position <= container.offsetWidth - slider.offsetWidth) {
            slider.style.left = new_slider_left_position + 'px';

        }

    }
}, true);
```

```css
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: cornflowerblue;
            border-radius: 5px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #slider {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 50px;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            cursor: move;
        }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the mouse moves so fast that it exits the window, then the slider doesn't run anymore.

Comment: it also happens, if the cursor doesn't leave the the window. I tried it many times

Comment: Hmm. Weird, if it moves too fast. Try another browser.